# Compare array slow

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use a standard way of comparing two arrays, but its as slow as just doing a standard O(n^2)
Can you guys see the problem?

```
    diffArray: function (arr1, arr2, observableArray, mapping) {
        //We cant sort orginal arrays
        var o = arr1.slice(0);
        var n = arr2.slice(0);

        // sort both arrays (or this won't work)
        var sorter = function (left, right) {
            return mapping.key(left) - mapping.key(right);
        };
        o.sort(sorter); n.sort(sorter);

        // declare temporary variables
        var op = 0; var np = 0;
        var added = []; var removed = [];

        // compare arrays and add to add or remove lists
        while (op < o.length && np < n.length) {
            if (mapping.key(o[op]) < mapping.key(n[np])) {
                // push to diff?
                removed.push(o[op]);
                op++;
            }
            else if (mapping.key(o[op]) > mapping.key(n[np])) {
                // push to diff?
                added.push(n[np]);
                np++;
            }
            else {
                this.diffMembers(o[op], n[np]);
                op++; np++;
            }
        }

        // add remaining items
        if (np < n.length)
            added = added.concat(n.slice(np, n.length));
        if (op < o.length)
            removed = removed.concat(o.slice(op, o.length));

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(removed, function (item) {
            this.itemDeleted(item, mapping);
        }.bind(this));


        ko.utils.arrayForEach(added, function (item) {
            if (observableArray.concurrencyExtendOptions) {
                this.itemAdded(observableArray, item, mapping);
            }
        } .bind(this));
    }
```

Note:
The mapping object is just a helper object the user supplies to compare objects in the array, arr1 and arr2 are standard JS arrays while observableArray is the unwrapped Knockout array

It's based on a C# code example so maybe the sort algorithm in JS isn't as good?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will answer you, really, but here is the `diff` I'm using for arrays:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function( arr ) {
    return arr.map( function( v ) {
        if ( !~this.indexOf( v ) ) return v;
    }, this ).filter( Boolean );
};
```

Usage:

```
arr.diff( otherArr );
```

<sub>PS: Too long to be posted as a comment... Not sure it deserves an answer.</sub>
<sub>PS2: Original author of the function: [@Esailija](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4021931#4021931).</sub>

Comment: Thats a classic O(n^2) diff, edit: well worst case close to n^2